# Is there a way to unsend a message using its unique message id? (Discord Py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In discord, I created a file based connect 4 game using buttons. I'm attempting to make it that if you recall the function, instead of creating a new game, it reopens your old game. This causes issues, as if you start the game and then reopen the game, the previous buttons still affect the file board but don't actively update the discord message, meaning what the board truly is and what it display is different. I can get message id and write in the file, meaning the bot can access the previous message id, but is there a way to delete the previous message?

Answer (score 2):

To delete a message on discord.py, you need to fetch the message with the message id and channel object, and then call the delete function.

```
  
try: # Error Check
  channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id) # Channel ID
  msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id) # Message ID
  await msg.delete() # Deleting
except Exception as e: # Error Check
  print(e)
```

Comment: How do you get channel_id? For message id its just msg.id, so is channel_id similar to msg.channel.id?

Comment: @LoganRothe yes

Answer (score 2):

To go off pelaajahacks
If m is your sent message

```
  print(m.id)
  print(m.channel.id)
# Use above to get id and channel
  try: # Error Check
      channel = bot.get_channel(m.channel.id) # Channel ID
      msg = await channel.fetch_message(m.id) # Message ID
      await msg.delete() # Deleting
  except Exception as e: # Error Check
    print(e)
```